# Date Format in VBA not Working

Tags: vba, excel, date

I want to display an input message response to a cell which is date formatted using CDate (dd/mm/yyyy).  Why is it the code is not showing the error message if input was done as dd/mm/yy?  The program accepts it but output shows as **yy/mm/dd**.

below is the code I created:

```
Sub inputSettlementDate()

Dim varInputDate As Variant
Dim lngERow As Long


varInputDate = InputBox("Please enter the Settlement Date using this format dd/mm/yyyy.", "Settlement Date")
If IsDate(varInputDate) Then
    varInputDate = Format(CDate(varInputDate), "dd/mm/yyyy")
  Else
   MsgBox "Please enter a valid date format dd/mm/yyyy"
End If

If IsDate(varInputDate) Then
   lngERow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
   Range("B" & lngERow).Value = varInputDate
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make sure Column B has a format as General, or that it doesn't have a yy/mm/dd format. I tested your code in a blank workbook without changing anything and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Hi...I've changed the format to General but it still the same.   On input box, I put in "24/3/16" instead of "24/3/2016".   I thought it will display an error message since the format is incorrect.  Output shows as "16/03/2024"..

Comment: OK, first off, something I hadn't answered before. If you put in dd/mm/yy, the line     IsDate(varInputDate) will still evaluate that as a valid date, and go into the regular processing, not showing an error. Try with a regular string, like "Hello world" and you'll get the error.

Secondly, CDate recognizes date formats according to the locale setting of your system. Try removing that.

Comment: it works!  it turn out there's nothing wrong with my (take note: very first) code.   thanks!

Comment: Please help again. When I opened my workbook and run the code it reverts back to the wrong date format.   I removed the CDate and replaced it with format but format date is showing it incorrectly as 04-06-2016 (mm-dd-yyyy) when it was 6/4/2016 (dd/mm/yyyy) that I keyed in through the input box.   I'm sure the code will not pick up my locale setting as I had removed the cdate.